# How to update a tile text every minute on Windows Phone 7 Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'd like to show a time remaining to some event on a Windows Phone live tile. The time left should be in minutes. I could live with updating every 2-5 minutes, but anything above that would render the tile nearly useless (I want to show information that gets stale fast).

I only really want to update text, but possibility to update image too would be great. Is there a way to do that in Windows Phone 7 Mango? If so, could you point me to some resources?

Comment: I've accepted Richard's answer below as it seems that tiles are not well suited for displaying time information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this on the client alone, as background agents run for at most <strike>25</strike> 15 seconds every 30 minutes.

If you setup a server component to your application, you can use push notifications to update the tile. It's not guaranteed how quickly the phone will receive it, though, so you should test it first. It also requires the phone has connectivity.

By default, there is a limit of 500 messages that can be sent per day. However, if you [secure your service with a TLS certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941099%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and then submit that certificate to the marketplace, you can send an unlimited number of messages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However this would mean that user has to be online for an application which uses only local data. Also I think that bombarding user with large amount of notifications would drain battery very quickly.

Comment: 15 seconds, just for the record.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to show a time remaining to some event on a Windows Phone live tile.

A [alarm/reminder task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202965%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) would any day be more suited for this, than any type of widget.

Comment: Well, not for my application. I guess I was too cautious in trying not reveal too much. What I'd like to show is time left till the next bus leaves from user pinned stop. I guess I'll have to resort to simply showing exact time and letting user to calculate time left for himself.

Answer (score 0):

If its just the background image of the tile then you can find some help
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltileschedule%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. It is advised that you explain your answer, how it works and provide (a piece of) code. With that, people are more likely to understand it and move on again. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for you advise Rune! I will keep them in mind.

Comment: @rune,I just added the link, as the question asked was ""If so, could you point me to some resources?"".